# Inheriting from a class that has __new__ returning another class in python

Tags: python, inheritance

If have a class like this one:

```
class ExA:
    def __new__(cls, obj):
        if type(obj) is dict:
            return ExADict(obj)
        if type(obj) is list
            return ExAList(obj)
```

Assuming I cannot change this class.
I want to inherit from it.

```
class ExB(ExA):
    def new_method(self):
        ...
```

I figure I need to write a __new__ method that would handle this but I can't figure it out. I think I don't fully understand how super() works.

```
class ExB(ExA):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        o = super().__new__(cls, list(arg))
```

"o" is an ExAList. I'm close. I now need to return the equivalent of `class ExB(ExAList)`. But I don't get how to do so. (I know I could just go with `class ExB(ExAList)` and don't bother with __new__ but at this point, I just want to know!! :)

Edit: How would you re write ExA to make this easier?

Comment: Do you have `ExBDict` and `ExBLis` classes? `ExA` is a textbook example of how *not* to write a factory function for a class you want to subclass, but it's not clear what you want `ExB.__new__` to return.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to define methods of `ExA` or its subclasses. When you use the `ExA` class, it doesn't actually create an instance of that class, it creates an `ExADict` or `ExAList`. The same thing happens if you create an instance of `ExB`, since it inherits the `__new__` method.

Comment: I do have ExAdict and ExAlist. I want ExB(obj) to instantiate an object that will be either an ExAlist with new_method or ExAdict with new_method depending on the type of obj.

Comment: So it seems I should just inherit from ExAlist directly, in my example.

Comment: Yes. `def ExA(obj): if type(obj) is dict: return ExADict(obj) ...` Similarly for `ExB`: define subclasses of `ExAList` and `ExADict`, and a function `ExB` that returns instances of the two as necessary.